# Tabulator - Disable editing for specific field

Tags: tabulator

I have a table in **Tabulator** where all fields are Editable.
I would like to be able to switch the edit function on and off for different fields after the table has loaded.

I can hide the column: `table.hideColumn("r1");`
but it would be great if I could disable the editing.
As a bonus i'd also like to reformat the disabled column (change the background colour)

```
 var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    height:"90%",
    layout:"fitData",
    ajaxURL:"data.php",
    placeholder:"Data Loading...",
    history:true,
    cellEdited:function(cell){console.log("cell changed: (" + cell.getOldValue() + ") [" + cell.getValue() + "] - field: " + cell.getField() + " - id: " + cell.getRow().getIndex());},
    columns:[
        {title:"id", field:"id", sorter:"number", visible:false},
        {title:"1", field:"r1", sorter:"number", editor:"input"},
        {title:"2", field:"r2", sorter:"number", editor:"input"},
        {title:"3", field:"r3", sorter:"number", editor:"input"},
        {title:"4", field:"r4", sorter:"number", editor:"input"},
        ],
});
```

Many Thanks

**AMEND - Added [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stutraystu/3t17wq0e/)**

Answer (score 1):

In order to change bg cell color and also its font color use:

```
cell.getElement().style.color= "#ffffff";  //CHANGE CELL WHITE FONT
cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#e68a00"; //CHANGE CELL BG COLOR
```

inside tabulator's title declaration..

for disabling editing try an object array with states: Let's say we have 3 columns and want only column 3 to be edited...

```
var isDisabled=["","","input"];
```

so you can use:

```
{title:"1", field:"r1", sorter:"number", editor:isDisabled[0].toString()},
{title:"2", field:"r2", sorter:"number", editor:isDisabled[1].toString()},
{title:"3", field:"r3", sorter:"number", editor:isDisabled[2].toString()}
```

Now you are ready to access these states directly in your array to change tabulator's edit status on the runtime!

Hope that helps!

**[UPDATE1]**

I've found this approach on Tabulator's [Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/edit):

```
var editCheck = function(cell){
    //cell - the cell component for the editable cell

    //get row data
    var data = cell.getRow().getData();

    return data.age > 18; // only allow the name cell to be edited if the age is over 18
}

//in your column definition for the column
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input", editable:editCheck}
```

You can add a differed approach on every column and you can set corresponding criteria. i Also noted that once tabulator loads its data there is no way of disabling/enabling cell editing. But with the above method you define edit-ability before loading data!

**[UPDATE2]**

Im using `cell.getColumn().getField();` to access columns name for triggering IF statement

```
var editCheck = function(cell){

var data = cell.getRow().getData();

if (incomingValue === 0){
   console.log("Enable All");
   return data;
}

if (incomingValue === 2 && cell.getColumn().getField()==="r1"){
   console.log("Disabled col1");
   return data.r1!==incomingValue; //FOR ENABLING EDIT TO OTHER COLUMNS EXCEPT THIS ONE
}

//... Here all IFs for the rest columns

};
```

Comment: Thanks for this George. This is great little trick, however what I'm after is being able to Disable the Columns according to a variable. e.g. if the variable=2 then col 1 to be disabled, If variable=6 then 1to5 to be disabled.

Comment: Your variable is a specific cell's value on every column or it is user defined?

Comment: The variable is defined when the page is loaded (from a different source than the Table data)

Comment: I've tried your edit but nothing seems to be firing. Please see the fiddle in the amended post. Thanks